# Maya python script - how to check coordinates UVShell

Tags: python, pipeline, maya

Maya python script - how to check coordinates UVShell

Is there a way to find the positions of all UV shells in the model, to know exactly where they are located?

I'm looking to determine whether this model has UV shells that intersect the boundaries of UDIM tiles. If the model spans multiple UDIMs but there's no overlap across the UDIM tile boundaries, it's considered acceptable. However, if a UV shell intersects the boundaries between UDIMs, I would like it to trigger a notification.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I want the positions of all UVShells, for example, for model1, there are a total of 5 UVShells. I would like to know the x min, x max, y min, and y max values of UVShell number 1, as well as the x min, x max, y min, and y max values of UVShell number 2 up to UVShell number 5.